# Clear space around sprite image registering pointer events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, click

I'm using Unity 5, withthe new uGUI system and I'm having a terrible time getting pointer events to ignore the clear space around my sprites and register only the image area. I've attached images and code to show where I'm at. I cannot get the this to work.

Ultimately, the thing I'm trying to achieve is to just have the click event interact with the image rather than the entire image sprite (everything in the rectangular bounding box).

My image texture type is Sprite (2D and UI). I made sure the space around my image is indeed transparent, yet the clear space around the image is still registering a click.

What am I doing wrong here? Need help!

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DragHandling : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public float partScale;

    [HideInInspector] public Transform placeholderParent = null;
    [HideInInspector] public Transform parentToReturnTo = null;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject trashCan; 
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject partsPanel;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject partsWindow;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject buildBoard;

    GameObject placeholder = null;
    GameObject dragLayer;
    Vector3 buildPanelScale;
    Vector3 partsPanelScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    Vector3 startPosition;

    void Start ()
    {
        dragLayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DragLayer");
        buildBoard = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Board");
        partsPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Parts");
        partsWindow = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PartsWindow");
        trashCan = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Trash");
    }

    #region IPointerClickHandler implementation

    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
            transform.SetAsLastSibling();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IBeginDragHandler implementation

    public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // create placeholder gap and hold correct position in layout
        placeholder = new GameObject();
        placeholder.transform.SetParent(transform.parent);
        placeholder.transform.SetSiblingIndex(transform.GetSiblingIndex());

        parentToReturnTo = transform.parent;                                    // store original parent location
        placeholderParent = parentToReturnTo;                                   // set placeholder gameobject transform

        startPosition = transform.position;

        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;                     // turn off image raycasting when dragging image in order to see what's behind the image            
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDragHandler implementation

    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, 0);

        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;                                           // set object coordinates to mouse coordinates

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
            transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);                                       // pop object to draglayer to move object out of parts Panel

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
            transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEndDragHandler implementation

    public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.SetParent(parentToReturnTo);                                  // Snaps object back to orginal parent if dropped outside of a dropzone
        transform.SetSiblingIndex(placeholder.transform.GetSiblingIndex());     // Returns card back to placeholder location

        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;                      // turn Raycast back on
        Destroy(placeholder);                                                   // kill the placeholder if object hits a drop zone or returns to parts panel

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
        {
            buildPanelScale = new Vector3(partScale, partScale, partScale);
            transform.localScale = buildPanelScale;
            transform.SetAsLastSibling();                                       // always place last piece on top
        }

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
            transform.localScale = partsPanelScale;
    }

    #endregion

}
```